# Joomla database - Get result from different table with results from first table

Tags: joomla

Basically i'm trying to get data from a table. When I pull all the row, I get the branch as ID, and i'm trying to cross refferance it with the branch table so I can get the title and display it. What is the proper way of doing this. I don't have much experiance with functions, but i'm thinking a function could come in handy here. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><h5>Title</h5></td>
<td><h5>Location</h5></td>
<td><h5>Time</h5></td>
</tr>
<?php


// Get a database object
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__jobs_description');

// sets up a database query for later execution
$db->setQuery($query);

// fetch result as an object list
$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ( $result as $row ) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row->title;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";

getbranchtitle($row->branch);

echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row->type;
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";


}

function getbranchtitle(){
// Get branch name
$db2 = JFactory::getDbo();
$query2
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'title')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__vna_jobs_branch'))
    ->where('id = '. ($row->branch))
    ->order('ordering ASC');
    $result2 = $db->loadObjectList();
    echo $result2->title;

}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved with a join instead of your current solution:

```
...
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('j.*');
$query->select('b.title as branchtitle');
$query->from('#__jobs_description', 'j');
$query->leftJoin('#__vna_jobs_branch b on (j.branch=b.id)')
// sets up a database query for later execution
$db->setQuery($query);
...
```

Now branchtitle will be directly available in your foreach-loop

```
...
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row->title;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
$row->branchtitle; // from your query join
echo "</td>";
...
```